# five part top layout

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to develop a 5 part top layout that will work on any browser. Its 5 part because you have the center menu that spans 1024.

Then you have a left and right side of the menu that has some non-repeating images that will run over into a repeating image that I want to go to infinity.

This has proven to be very hard, and I've probably forgotten that it could be impossible...

What I have done is get so close I can almost taste it. If you could look at my code and tell me what's going on with the "right_side" and it's width - it's causing some serious trouble with the scrollbar.

Image of what I'm talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzj6c.jpg

The following is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            .left_stretch{
                background-color:red;
                z-index:-10;
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                width:50%;
                height:100%;
            }
            .left_side{
                background-color:blue;
                z-index:-5;
                position:relative;
                top:0px;
                right:512px;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            .center{
                background-color:green;
                height:500px;
                width:1024px;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
            }
            .right_side{
                background-color:grey;
                z-index:50;
                position:relative;
                top:0px;
                left:512px;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            .right_stretch{
                background-color:orange;
                z-index:-10;
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                right:0px;
                width:50%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="left_stretch">
            <div class="left_side"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="center"></div>
        <div class="right_stretch">
            <div class="right_side"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then I'm of course worried that ie 7 and ie 6 is messing things up... But I just want to solve this first...

Any hints at all?

Comment: Can you send us an image of your design (a sketch), specifying what you mean visually? :)

Comment: Couldnt find any definite giveaways from the code but as a hint.. you should seriously get Firebug ( for firefox ) or use some other development tool to check out that "empty" area

Answer (score 0):

Realized that i can jsfiddle your code, so i tested it.

It's your `<div class="right_side"></div>` whats causing it.. its just basically hanging in there.. creating the space.

I'm not really sure why the structure is like this so im not gonna give any hints as far as fixing it goes. ..unless you want a quick fix.. which is to delete that element :D